# How to avoid duplicate property declaration. In C# Class

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0

```
public class Test
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Subject {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
    public string Phone {get;set;}  
}

public class Test1
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Subject {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
    public string Phone {get;set;}  
    public int Time {get;set;}
    publicg string Result {get;set;}
}
public class Test2
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Subject {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
    public string Phone {get;set;}  
}

public class Test3
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public string Subject {get;set;}
    public string Address {get;set;}
    public string Phone {get;set;}  
    public int Time {get;set;}
    publicg string Result {get;set;}
}
```

I All,
I Have One big doubt,
here I have created Four Class in that Four class you can see some of the Common Properties,
in one of my project there is 500 Class where these type of common (Duplicate) properties are there I tried my best to solve this problem using one Separate Class there I have taken all duplicate property and Inherited that class to all classes, but the problem is that common class have 1000 Property after filtered the all class property when I am using that class its giving me Outofmemory exception and performance also get down.
Example:-

```
public Class A:CommonClass
{
   public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

here Class A have 30 duplicate Properties after inherit Common class all duplicate property I have removed. but when I am using this A class for any Data binding from DB its  and taking that data to bind any Grid or Dropdown its Throwing OutofMemory Exception.
what is the best way to solve this issue. Please help me.

Comment: 1000 properties on a single class is a bit of a code smell and suggests you may need to Refactor some things (possibly including your db)

Comment: because of all Common properties are there in that class and i don't want any duplicate properties in other class. and I can't do DB Changes.
is there any Idea. to avoid this.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the OutOfMemoryException? Moving properties to a base class, (or better, use composition rather then inheritance) should only cause a minor memory increase. So it might be a bug in the code.